# Why does polyglossia read hyph-fr.pat.txt twice?

Tags: polyglossia, french

Consider the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Compile with `luatex` shipped with TeXLive 2016, you get on the terminal:

```
Language data for francais
hyphenation 
loader  loadhyph-fr.tex
patterns    hyph-fr.pat.txt
righthyphenmin  2
synonyms    table: 0x4556dd0
lefthyphenmin   2

hyph-fr.pat.txt
Language francais was not yet loaded; created with id 4
Language francais already loaded; id is 4
Language francais already loaded; id is 4

Language data for french
hyphenation 
loader  loadhyph-fr.tex
patterns    hyph-fr.pat.txt
righthyphenmin  2
synonyms    table: 0x4556dd0
lefthyphenmin   2

hyph-fr.pat.txt
Language french was not yet loaded; created with id 8
Language french already loaded; id is 8)
```

So it seems that hyph-ft.pat.txt is read twice, one for `francais` and the other for `french`. Is there a valid reason or is this a bug?

Comment: Reported at [`polyglossia` tracker](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/156).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern file is not read twice, only the metadata is.  We could of course have an alias mechanism in order to load it only once, and have one option point to the other; but it doesn’t exist at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. Ok but why french and francais?